# Speed Up Checking for Equality in Haskell

Tags: haskell, optimization, profiling

Is it possible to speed up (or in the case of my function, remove) the checking of equality in Haskell? I have a function that sums the all of the interaction of an agent, where interactions are between two agents. To sum the interaction, it first has to check whether the agent is equal to the first or second agent in the interaction, and then sums it. Checking for equality takes up almost half of my programs running time.

```
sumAgent :: [Interaction] -> Agent -> Int
sumAgent xs agent = foldr (\x acc -> acc + sumInteraction agent x) 0 xs

-- Use this in a map call of sumAgent to return the sums of a specific agent
sumInteraction :: Agent -> Interaction  -> Int
sumInteraction agent (Interaction a1 a2 xs )
    | (==) agent a1 = sum $ map fst scores
    | (==) agent a2 = sum $ map snd scores
    | otherwise = 0
    where scores = map score xs
```

Is it possible to remove the equality checking, or to speed it up, by using a c function, or checking the equality of only part of the agent? The Eq implementation is:

```
  data Agent = Agent {
                function::[(Bool,Bool)] -> Bool,
                name::String,
                position::(Int,Int),
                dna::DNA
               }
 instance Eq Agent where
        (==) a1 a2 = position a1 == position a2
```

Comment: You have provided not enough information to answer your questions.  `position` may be an expensive computation as well as record getter. Also consider refactoring of algorithm and data structures. Likely it will be cheaper to maintain lists of incident interactions per agent, than filter common list of interactions each time you need to aggregate interactions of the agent.

Comment: Also, make sure you compile the program with `-O2` flag when you want to estimate performance.

Comment: By the way, you can always place infix operators between the arguments: `| agent == a1 = ...`, `a1 == a2 = pos...`

Comment: @leventov, Just `-O` suffices.  I always though `-O2` meant "optimize more", but really it means "do some experimental optimizations which might accidentally make your code slower".

Comment: @luqui I disagree, your point is too conservative. Actually I just cited http://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info

Comment: @leventov, if you don't check for yourself on your specific program, it's a matter of taste which to use (but `-O` is what cabal uses when building libraries, and has the most stable and reliably code-improving optimizations).  I was just always perplexed why there were different levels -- why wouldn't I want to optimize more?  That's why.

Comment: @liqui I thought cabal's main intent is faster compilation, not hypothetical slowdown of programs. Isn't it?

Comment: As an aside, declaring equality as just positionally equality is a code smell. I agree with @leventov's first comment - potentially your algorithm / data structures aren't as good as they could be at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

How do you know equality is taking half the time?  I am guessing you're most likely to get a performance benefit by using strict and unboxed pairs:

```
 data Pair = P {-# UNPACK #-} !Int {-# UNPACK #-} !Int
 data Agent = Agent {
            function::[(Bool,Bool)] -> Bool,
            name::String,
            position:: {-# UNPACK #-} !Pair Int Int,
            dna::DNA
           }
```

This way you'll avoid the extra indirection and probably get better cache behavior.